# Changing the Replication Distributor Server

Tags: sql-server

Scenario:

We have Server A, a current distributor server that also does some publishing (but not the exclusive publisher servers).  We have servers C, D, E, F and G.  All of these are subscribers to the publishers.  We have a Server B that we want to exclusively use for distributing, no publishing.  We want all replication to use Server B as the distributor and not Server A, meaning that I can either slowly switch publication at a time, or change the configuration, relative to what option is available (unfortunately, this is not as clear as I had hoped in MS articles).

Questions:

1. Can a publisher server have two distributor, such as in the above example, can Server A and Server B both be distributors, where Server B distributes for some of Server A's publishers and Server A also distributes for some of its own publishers as well?  In configurations, the below code would return two values for distributor - Server A and Server B:

   USE master
   GO

   EXEC sp_helpdistributor
2. Assuming the question for **option 1** is not possible, if I were to remove Server A as the distributor and replace it with Server B, what's the offline time for all the publications in existence on Server A, meaning is replication set up to where a simple `configuration change` doesn't disrupt the process (like a mirror aware connection string), or will this cause a massive outage?

Thanks!